# Hover effect not working as expected - UI responsivness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here is [the plunker where I am trying to make](https://plnkr.co/edit/DOXlTjwVtoa1gWfbeqLh?p=preview) "All Conversations" responsive.

I have used below styling:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #user-list {
    display: none;
  }
  #dropdownMenu2:hover > #user-list{
    display: block;
  }
  #dropdownMenu2:hover{
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

1. What I want to achieve is to show the "All Conversations" list once the UI is small. I can see that the `background: yellow` is working but I cant see the id `#user-list`
2. If possible please suggest the toggle behavior for the same using `data-toggle` and `data-target` . I tried but it wasn't working :(

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is wrong, what you are saying is that #user-list is a child of #dropdownMenu2.

in your code i can see that #user-list is not a child nor a sibling.
you have the button wrapped in div (dropdown all_conversation).

Either move the user list inisde the div just after the button #dropdownMenu2, or remove the wrapping div.

then you can change the css rule to:

```
#dropdownMenu2:hover + #user-list{
    display: block;
  }
```

Edit:

Sorry for late reply.

after seeing your update, you are giving absolute to the wrong element.

chat-msgs should remain relative.

change the rule according

```
@media (max-width: 767px){    
#dropdownMenu2:hover + #user-list, #user-list:hover {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #fff;
}
}
```

about hover in mobile, it is indeed not really consistent. I prefer using click for mobile, and all hover effects are:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px){
   //all hover rules
}
```